# Chrome on MacOS – Zoom In (cmd - plus) not working after update

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

After updating Mac OS a while ago, I cannot zoom in in Chrome using `cmd-plus` any longer. Zooming out (`cmd-minus`) and zooming to 100 (`cmd-0`) works just fine.

(according to [the docs](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en#zippy=%2Cwebpage-shortcuts) – "webpage shortcuts", and common sense, it should still work)

I would have expected this to be fixed within a day, but I couldn't even find any open threads or issues. I could replicate this on 4 different Mac OS machines (both silicon and Intel), so I guess it's not related to anything local.
My specs:

```
Chrome Version 97.0.4692.99 (Official Build) (arm64)
MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020), Mac OS 12.1 (21C52)
```

My questions are:

- am I missing something obvious here, or is this an actual bug?
- did I just not find a bug ticket for this, or is there none?

Comment: 2 posts so far today - suspect bug - https://superuser.com/questions/1701712/how-to-reset-hotkeys-for-zoom-in-out-in-google-chrome

Comment: Related: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1286243

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome 98 it has been "fixed" and now the shortcut is <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Wow, I really don't understand this, but truly it works.