# How to reset hotkeys for zoom in/out in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have a really strange issue with my Chrome brwoser:

Suddenly my `CMD +` shortcut for zoom in wasn't working anymore. I checked the menu and now the shortcut to zoom in is `CMD =`??? I attachted a screenshot, which is in German - sorry for that, but I think you can the issue.

I tried to find a solution, but the only thing I found is this link to reddit
https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/lb4tnr/how_to_change_the_hotkey_shortcut_for_zoom_in_or/

But I can't find the options "keyboard" or "shortcuts" in my Chrome settings

I'm using this version of Chrome `Version 97.0.4692.99`

It would be really cool, if you could help me out!

Comment: Second time that's been mentioned today. I'd suspect a bug - https://superuser.com/questions/1701506/chrome-on-macos-zoom-in-cmd-plus-not-working-after-update

Comment: As a workaround you can create [your own keyboard shortcut](https://osxdaily.com/2017/08/08/create-custom-keyboard-shortcut-mac/) in System Preferences.

Comment: In Chrome 98 you can use ⌘ + Shift + "+" - don't know why.

Comment: Related: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1286243

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chrome guys replaced the old shortcut for *zoom-IN* with <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> .. ‍♂️

And they let the old shortcut for *zoom-OUT* untouched, but adding also <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>, making it seem like a buggy behaviour.

Here is the related bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1286243 .